# Getting HTTP 400 Bad request on Angular 5/ASP.NET Core 2 project

Tags: csrf, asp.net-core-2.0, angular5

I'm having troubles configuring XSRF for my Angular 5/ASP.NET Core 2 project.

On the Server I've added in Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => { options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN"; });
```

and in Startup.Configure:

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
                var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions
                    {
                        HttpOnly = false,
                        Secure = false
                    }
                );
            await next();
        });
```

and I call this method to test:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        return new JsonResult("good");
    }
```

On the Angular side, I have in app.module.ts:

```
    imports: [
      HttpClientModule,
      HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
        cookieName: 'XSRF-COOKIE',
        headerName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      }), ...
```

Then, when I call my Post method, I get this:

[image: Request and response in Chrome]

[image: cookies]

I get a HTTP 400 bad request error... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Is there a question in all that other than what are you doing wrong?

Comment: Any chance you managed to fix this error? Currently experiencing the same.

Comment: no, I haven't found a fix :(